# ContentTemplateSelector item is null

Tags: c#, winui-3

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="FlatSymbolIconButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder">
        <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FlatButtonTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource FlatSymbolIconButton}" Content="Edit"/>
```

The SelectTemplateCore method is called, but item == null. I thought parameter content gets passed to that method (in my case a string containing 'Edit') so I can select the template based on the Content property.

Just for testing I decided to return a default template. The curious thing is, that the content is passed correctly to the data template and displayed correctly.

What could be the reason, why the item parameter is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `TemplateSelector` directly to  the `Button`?

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector x:Key="FlatButtonTemplateSelector">
        <local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector.EditTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--  Template for "Edit" here.  -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector.EditTemplate>
        <local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--  Default template here.  -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
    </local:FlatButtonTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button
        Content="Edit"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FlatButtonTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class FlatButtonTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate EditTemplate { get; set; }


    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is string itemString &&
            item is "Edit")
        {
            return EditTemplate;
        }

        return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I actually tried your code and the `SelectTemplateCore` method gets called twice. I guess the first one, `item` being `null`, is when the `ControlTemplate` is instantiated, and the second one, `item` with **Edit** as its content, is when the `Content` is set.

Comment: You might be interested in this [video](https://youtu.be/MPUue7mg4EE?si=R3-hKDMOx1re5F1c) of mine about how to use the `TemplateSelector` with several `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have not tried that. I stripped down my example a bit. The reason why I want to do it that way, is because I want to reuse the Border and the VisualState declarations associated with it. I just want to use different Controls to display the Content/Icon (e.g. SymbolIcon, Image, BitmapIcon etc)

Comment: I changed so many things and it never worked. Weirdly, my stripped down example worked and I didn't notice it. because it is called twice like you said. Thanks for your time and examples. I still learned something.